# Jquery ajax call not working when page is deployed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

We have a simple jquery ajax call

we made a more button and on button click it call another php file

on my local computer server its working good even once it work good on when i made it live on server but suddenly it stop working live.

Following code working good on local computer server but when i made it live then its not working

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<div align="center"><input type="button" id="morejobs" class="m-btn blue buttonSmall tmargin"  data="?id=111&page=2" value="More Jos &raquo;" /></div>
```

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$("#morejobs").click(function () {

    var datavalue = $(this).attr("data");
    //$("#morejobs").text('Loading..');    
    if (datavalue) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "new_keyword_city_common.php",
            data: datavalue,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#friendsugmore").html('');
                $("#friendsugmore").html(data);
            }
        });

    }

    return false;
});

</script>
```

What can be issue when same code working good on local server but not live

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Are there errors? Have you verified that the ajax call is being attempted?

Comment: This is not enough information to answer your question.

Comment: Does the console shows any error on the live server? Is the new_keyword_city_common.php are there and has the proper rights? Since, you are using GET method, you can try to call yourserver.com/path/to/new_keyword_city_common.php?param1=value1 What is the result of that?

Comment: my guess would be that the index and `new_keyword_city_common.php` are in the root of your local server but in a sub folder on the live server hit f12 and check your net tab and console for errors

Comment: Hello Not working means when i click on more then page is not calling

Comment: for testing i put alert then i find that alert not working after success: function(data){ it means ajax is not success. the file is also on root and its working good in my local computer server then why not live

Comment: ok. finally i find the issue. this is issue of base href. i have base href in header file. when i remove that then code working good otherwise not. but i can not remove base href. so what to do now?

Comment: Side-Note: `$("#friendsugmore").html('');` is redundant as the line following it replaces the innerHTML completely.

Comment: the all issue is base href. i have remove $("#friendsugmore").html('');

Answer (score 2):

You say your files are in the root. What you can try is to add `/` before the file to force it to take the root:

```
url: "/new_keyword_city_common.php",
```

If this doesn't work try an absolute path. Add the whole domain name before the PHP file. For example:

```
url: "http://yourdomainhere.com/new_keyword_city_common.php",
```

Comment: both not working and also ajax do not allow domain level